# Product of exponential and harmonic series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm currently working with an infinite series given by

$$
1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \ldots = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k}{(k+1)!}
$$

This is clearly very close to the exponential series

$$
e^{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$

but not quite there. Is it possible to separate the sum in my series into a hormonic series and exponential series, such that

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k}{(k+1)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^{x}\ln 2 
$$

Alternatively, is there any other simplification that can be made?

Comment: Multiply your series by $-x$, this turns it into $e^{-x}-1$, so it is just $\frac{1-e^{-x}}x$.

Comment: That isn't a product of an exponential and a harmonic series; it's certainly not $e^x\ln2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}\dfrac{(-x)^{k}}{(k+1)!}&=-\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}\dfrac{(-x)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}\dfrac{(-x)^{k}}{k!}\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{k=0}\dfrac{(-x)^{k}}{k!}-1\right)\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{x}(e^{-x}-1).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{-x} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}  \\
\mathrm{e}^{-x} &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}  \\
\mathrm{e}^{-x} - 1 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}  &&  k \mapsto k+1  \\
    &= -x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{k}}{(k+1)!}  &&  \text{ so}  \\
\frac{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}}{x} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{k}}{(k+1)!}  &&  \text{.}
\end{align*}